# Setting sbt-pgp passphrase the global configuration in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

[This page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-pgp/usage.html) suggests I can add the following to a file in ~/.sbt/*.sbt

```
pgpPassphrase := Some(Array('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

When I do I get the error

```
~/.sbt/pgp.sbt:1: error: reassignment to val
pgpPassphrase := Some(Array('a', 'b', 'c'))
^
```

I'm not sure how (or if I can) override a setting in SBT.

Comment: Are you using sbt 0.12 or 0.13? The global configuration's default location changed in 0.13 to `~/.sbt/0.13/`.

Comment: 0.12, as 0.13 is not supported by heroku yet. That plugin page doesn't offer a link to prior versions.

Comment: Is there an update on this problem? I'm on 0.13.11. I've placed a file in `~/.sbt/0.13/pgp.sbt` and set the `pgpPassphrase` there, however, I still get prompted. This link https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/issues/69 suggests to do a fully qualified keys, but that still does NOT help.

Answer (score 2):

### setup

With my setup I have `~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt`:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "0.8")
```

and `~/.sbt/global.sbt`:

```scala
pgpPassphrase := Some(Array('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

This is probably the same as what you already have.

### other issues?

There may be other issues that are loading the sbt-pgp incorrectly. One possibility is that older version of the plugin is still within the classpath. Try cleaning the build project as follows:

```
> reload plugin
> clean
> reload return
```

Also make sure that the build you're loading isn't loading sbt-pgp plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using sbt 0.13.11. This is what I've done.

In `~/.sbt/plugins` I have added this file `~/.sbt/plugins/gpg.sbt`. Its content is as follows.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "1.0.0")
```

In my project's `site.sbt`, I've added the line.

```
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "1.1")
```

I've tried to add this line `pgpPassphrase := Some(Array('a', 'b', 'c'))` to the following locations and they either fail due to syntax or continue to prompt me for a passphrase.

- `~/.sbt/global.sbt`
- `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`

The **ONLY** way I was able to get the build to stop asking me for a passphrase was to inject it directly into my `build.sbt` file. For example,

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.something",
    version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    publishTo := {
        val nexus = "http://nexus.something.io/"
        if (isSnapshot.value)
            Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
        else
            Some("releases"  at nexus + "content/repositories/releases")
    },
    publishArtifact in Test := false,
    pomIncludeRepository := { _ => false },
    pomExtra := (
            <url>http://gitlab.something.io/something/project</url>
            <scm>
                <url>git@gitlab.something.io:something/project</url>
                <connection>scm:git:git@gitlab.something.io:something/project.git</connection>
                <developerConnection>scm:git:git@gitlab.something.io:something/project.git</developerConnection>
            </scm>
            <developers>
                <developer>
                    <email>myemail@gmail.com</email>
                    <name>my name</name>
                    <url>https://github.com/mysite</url>
                    <id>myid</id>
                    <organization>My Org</organization>
                    <organizationUrl>https://github.com/me</organizationUrl>
                </developer>
            </developers>),
    pgpPassphrase := Some(Array('a','b','c'))
)
```

Alternatively, I was able to define it else where too in `build.sbt`.

```
lazy val project = (project in file("."))
      .settings(commonSettings: _*)
      .settings(pgpPassphrase := Some(Array('a','b','c')))
      .settings(name := "my-project")
      .settings(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps)
      .settings(parallelExecution in Test := false)
      .settings(javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"))
```

My weakness is that I don't know enough about SBT, but the documents online do say you can create a file to externalize `pgpPassphrase`, but it never clearly states how to do so (and that's part of the problem of this post). Empircally, placing/setting `pgpPhassphrase` in `~/.sbt` or `~/.sbt/0.13` does not work.

I suppose I'll be searching for how to externalize values for the `.settings()` in `build.sbt`. But if anyone beats me to it, that would be appreciated.

Note: clearly, we should **NOT** be placing the passphrase in build.sbt (or a file that is versioned in SCM).

Here is somewhat of a workaround #1.

```
lazy val project = (project in file("."))
      .settings(commonSettings: _*)
      .settings(pgpPassphrase := scala.util.Properties.propOrNone("gpg.passphrase").map(_.toCharArray))
      .settings(name := "my-project")
      .settings(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps)
      .settings(parallelExecution in Test := false)
      .settings(javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"))
```

With this, you can call sbt as follows: `sbt -Dgpg.passphrase=abc publish-signed`.

Workaround #2.

```
lazy val project = (project in file("."))
      .settings(commonSettings: _*)
      .settings(pgpPassphrase := Some(System.getenv("GPG_PASSPHRASE").toCharArray))
      .settings(name := "my-project")
      .settings(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps)
      .settings(parallelExecution in Test := false)
      .settings(javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"))
```

With this approach, you'd have to export the passphrase `export GPG_PASSPHRASE=abc` and then you'd just run `sbt publish-signed`.

It's interesting to note that if you export your passphrase, the following line doesn't pick up the value (at least in my environment): `.settings(pgpPassphrase := scala.util.Properties.envOrNone("GPG_PASSPHRASE").map(_.toCharArray))`

I think workaround #2 might be better since you can export the passphrase in your bash profile.

I just found out that inside `build.sbt`, `scala.util.Properties.envOrNone` can't find an environment variable like `GPG_PASSPHRASE`. If I just export something like this `export gpg.passphrase=abc`, then bash complains. As a middle ground, if I do `export gpgpassphrase=abc`, then I can do `.settings(pgpPassphrase := scala.util.Properties.envOrNone("gpgpassphrase").map(_.toCharArray))` in my `build.sbt` and simply call `sbt publish-signed`.

It's interesting to note that in the scala REPL, `scala.util.Properties.envOrNone('GPG_PASSPHRASE')` does actually work (just not in `build.sbt`).

Answer (score 0):

With the last version of the plugin I made it running with next steps.

Version used:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "2.1.2")
```

First add next plugin to have a control on environment variables:

```
addSbtPlugin("au.com.onegeek" %% "sbt-dotenv" % "2.1.146")
```

Then create a file .env on your repository (important to add it in your .gitignore, this file should never be in the remote repo)

Inside the file store your passphrase env variable:

```
PGP_PASSPHRASE="your_passphrase_here"
```

Then you can try to run again, it should work.

> Important to note that is not a recommended setup as someone with
> access to your machine can get the passphrase easily.